# While Loop stops working before condition C++

Tags: c++

The while loop should stop at 12 but ends at 9. Also, please ignore I spelled inches incorrectly.

```
int main() { 
  double rainFall[12]; 
  int i = 0; 

  while(rainFall[i] > 0 && i < 12 ){ 

    cout << "Enter your rainfaill in incehs for month #" << i + 1 << ": " ; 
    cin >> rainFall[i]; 
    i++;
  }
}
```

Input / Output: 
Enter your rainfaill in incehs for month #1: 9

Enter your rainfaill in incehs for month #2: 9

Enter your rainfaill in incehs for month #3: 9

Enter your rainfaill in incehs for month #4: 9

Enter your rainfaill in incehs for month #5: 9

Enter your rainfaill in incehs for month #6: 9

Enter your rainfaill in incehs for month #7: 9

Enter your rainfaill in incehs for month #8: 9

Enter your rainfaill in incehs for month #9: 9

Comment: `rainFall[i]` is not initialized, whats the condition supposed to do?

Comment: It is supposed to go through each value in the array to make sure each integer is positive.

Comment: @Oliver You missed the point of the previous comment. `rainFall`'s initial values are not specified, each element is in an unspecified state. It's an error to try to read them or to assume that the array is zero initialized.

Comment: Use a do while in my opinion

Comment: There are no comments in your code and no explanation of what it's supposed to do. This means we have to make guesses when trying to fix it. For example, is it supposed to stop accepting entries when it gets a negative entry? Or is it always supposed to accept 12 entries? You don't say, and it's not clear whether that is or isn't the purpose of the `rainFall[i] > 0` test.

Comment: Uninitialised array elements are *indeterminate*, they are *not* magically zero. And reading uninitialised data is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @Oliver Would you please edit your question to include an explicit description of the desired behavior, and the actual behavior that you are observing?  It's also usually a good idea to include any debugging steps you've already attempted, and why you think the code you've written should be working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The condition you check is wrong, as you have uninitialized array of doubles and you check whether values inside `rainFall[]` are bigger than 0, while they can have any value that `double` can have. Just change the `while` condition to `(i < 12)` and it should work as you wish.

Comment: I think the OP wants to stop as soon as a negative rainfall amount is enetered, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Still it is not correct, he would have to check it after each value is entered and then use `if (rainFall[i] < 0) break;`.

Answer (score 1):

Just have replace the while loop with

```
int main() { 
  double rainFall[12]; 
  int i = 0
  while(i<12){
    cout << "Enter your rainfaill in incehs for month #" << i + 1 << ": " ; 
    cin >> rainFall[i]; 
    i++;
  }
}
```

the extra check for the double is unnecessary, because a double is able to be a negative. If you are looking to have it check for an error with the <0 statement, i would recommend use `throw` and `catch` statements.
Good documentation for those here https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_exceptions.asp

Comment: I wouldn't throw an exception. A negative rainfall is an input error and input errors are what you should expect from a meatbag at a keyboard. They aren't exceptional, so the error should be trapped and a new input entered, or whatever handling is required..

Comment: Sidenote: The link is of questionable value. The advice it gives is poor, and flat out wrong at points. Most notably *When an error occurs, C++ will normally stop and generate an error message.* I wish C++ was kind enough to do this. It would make everyone's lives much, much easier.

Comment: @user4581301 The catch statement would be used for the purposes of OP's development. Otherwise I agree that you could just have a condition elsewhere to verify the credibility of the argument entered.